# How can I correctly decompress a ZIP archive of files with Hebrew names?

Tags: character-encoding, zip, unicode, file-format

Someone sent me a ZIP file containing files with Hebrew names (and created on Windows, not sure with which tool). I use LXDE on Debian Stretch. The Gnome archive manager manages to unzip the file, but the Hebrew characters are garbled. I *think* I'm getting UTF-8 octets extended into Unicode characters, e.g. I have a file whose name has four characters and a .doc suffic, and the characters are: 0x008E 0x0087 0x008E 0x0085 . Using the command-line unzip utility is even worse - it refuses to decompress altogether, complaining about an "Invalid or incomplete multibyte or wide character".

So, my questions are:

- Is there another decompression utility that will decompress my files with the correct names?
- Is there something wrong with the way the file was compressed, or is it just an incompatibility of ZIP implementations? Or even misfeature/bug of the Linux ZIP utilities?
- What can I do to get the correct filenames after  having decompressed using the garbled ones?

Comment: If you look up those bytes in [the cp862 table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_862#Code_page_layout) does the file name match what you expect? Otherwise, do you know the native encoding of the source machine?

Comment: Ditto for [cp1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255), and any other plausible encodings; it may be possible to just work it out based on what looks right.

Comment: @MichaelHomer: No, it doesn't look like it matches. The native encoding of the source machine is whatever MS Windows uses when you set the regional settings to Hebrew-Israel, so I guess it's sometimes UTF-8 and sometimes CP1255.

Comment: There is a bug report for "Archive Manager" (internally file-roller) that contains a wealth of useful information: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/file-roller/+bug/495880

Comment: You can try `unzip -O cp862 -o "$sub_file"` the. The code page 862 is the code page used to for Hebrew. If your archive is also encrypted with a password, then you're out of luck with the `unzip` command because the password needs to be encoded in Hebrew too.

Comment: @oeter: This happened to me 8 years ago...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like the filenames are encoded in one of Windows' proprietary codepages ([CP862](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_862#Code_page_layout), [1255](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1255), etc).

- **Is there another decompression utility that will decompress my files with the correct names?** I'm not aware of a zip utility that supports these code pages natively. 7z has some understanding of encodings, but I believe it has to be an encoding your system knows about more generally (you pick it by setting the `LANG` environment variable) and Windows codepages likely aren't among those.

  `unzip -UU` should work from the command line to create files with the correct bytes in their names (by disabling all Unicode support). That is probably the effect you got from GNOME's tool already. The encoding won't be right either way, but we can fix that below.
- **Is there something wrong with the way the file was compressed, or is it just an incompatibility of ZIP implementations? Or even misfeature/bug of the Linux ZIP utilities?** The file you've been given was not created portably. That's not necessarily *wrong* for an internal use where the encoding is fixed and known in advance, although the format specification says that names are supposed to be either UTF-8 or cp437 and yours are neither. Even between Windows machines, using different codepages doesn't work out well, but non-Windows machines have no concept of those code pages to begin with. Most tools UTF-8 encode their filenames (which still isn't always enough to avoid problems).
- **What can I do to get the correct filenames after having decompressed using the garbled ones?** If you can identify the encoding of the filenames, you can convert the bytes in the existing names into UTF-8 and move the existing files to the right name. [The `convmv` tool](https://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/) essentially wraps up that process into a single command: `convmv -f cp862 -t utf8 -r .` will try to convert everything inside `.` from cp862 to UTF-8.

  Alternatively, you can use `iconv` and `find` to move everything to their correct names. Something like:

  ```
  find -mindepth 1 -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo "$1" | iconv -f cp862 -t utf8)"' sh {} \;
  ```

  will find all the files underneath the current directory and try to convert the names into UTF-8.

  In either case, you can experiment with different encodings and try to find one that makes sense.

---

After you've fixed the encoding for you, if you want to send these files back in the other direction it's possible you'll have the same problem on the other end. In that case, you can reverse the process before zipping the files up with `-UU`, since it's likely to be very hard to fix on the Windows end.

Comment: I guess this will have to do since the ZIP file I was looking into is now gone for, well, reasons irrelevant here. Thanks, will do this next time and hope for the best.

Comment: `rar` or `p7zip` refuse to handle .zip archives.
Is there a way to extract an archive with filenames in proprietary encodings, on Linux? When I extract with `unzip`, I get an error: "error:  cannot create ╨и╨╕╨┐/Ship_╨п ╨Я╤А╨╛╤З╨╗╨░ ╨Я╤А╨╛ ╨н╤В╨╛ ╨▓╨Ю╨┤╨╜╨╛╨╣ ╨Ъ╨╜╨╕╨╢╨║╨╡!.png File name too long"

Comment: I managed to extract .zip file correctly with `LANG=ru_RU.CP1251; unzip Bleed.zip` (it was Cyrillic encoding in my case). Now I wonder how do I set up my system so that I can correctly open such .zip files in GUI by default?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov [Ask a question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) and someone may be able to help you. You'll probably need to provide more information about your system.

Comment: `unzip -UU foo.zip` worked for Turkish characters

Comment: About `convmv`: in my case at least, `unzip`’s output does not even follow a valid encoding (e.g. distinct Cyrillic letters are mapped to the same byte sequence). It’s just ASCII-compatible garbage, with no similarity to any existing encoding. So the “decompress files then transcode filenames” method is not applicable. `7z` on the other hand decoded my filenames just fine, so the information *is* somewhere in the zip archive.

Answer (score 17):

I had success with the command `7z x <source.zip>`.

Version:

```
p7zip Version 16.02 (locale=utf8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 bits,[...])
```

Potentially relevant environment:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
```

It was able to decompress all files with 8-bit characters in their filenames, with some of these characters skipped, some garbled.

Comment: p7zip is the only one that worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I have just had the same problem, and it turns out that my version of `unzip` that is available from Ubuntu repositories (`UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.`) can handle automatic decoding of filenames if you specify the `-a` switch.

```
unzip -a stupid.zip
```

Comment: +1 although I have nothing to test this with right now.

Comment: According to the man page of `unzip` the `-a` switch takes care of converting text files. Not file names.

Comment: @beruic, I had unzipped unicode numbers as file names (#U+0040#U+0050...), and then "unzip -a" really helped.

Comment: I tried this on some manga. The filenames were decoded correctly, but the images were also interpreted as text (!) and corrupted completely. It even interprets zip and rar files inside the archive as text, the detection is completely useless.

Comment: +1 for the awesome file name

Answer (score 5):

I had luck with this combination:

```
export LANG=es_MX 
7z x file.zip
convmv -f cp437 -t utf8 -r .
```

add --notest to convmv for actual rename. Later I found even better version:

```
LANG=es_MX.cp437 unzip -UU file.zip
convmv -f cp437 -t utf8 -r . --notest
```

Comment: +1 just for convmv and the command-line 7zip tool.

Comment: Probably one has to try different options for `LANG` variable and _from_ encoding depending on the file at hand. I've got a file where `LANG=ru_RU.CP1251` together with `-f cp866` worked.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with decoding a zip archive with cyrillic characters. A one line python script did the job properly:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import zipfile
import sys

zipfile.ZipFile(sys.argv[1], 'r').extractall(sys.argv[2] if len(sys.argv) > 2 else '.')
```

Then just call it `unzip_enc` and call it `unzip_enc ZIP_FILE [TARGET_DIR]`

For me neither the `unzip -UU`,  `unzip -a` nor `LANG*` environment variables did any good.

Comment: I'll try that next time I have such a zip file to extract... thanks. But - could you change your script so as to: 1. check whether there are two arguments 2. extract to the current working directory if only the zip file is provided?

Comment: It extracts, but the filenames are still jibberish. Is there a way to decode the filenames into unicode?

Answer (score 1):

This issue with zips has been [fixed](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l/commit/73a19074dbe81fd25913dc5282825cb2ca9f8ceb) in the most recent [far2l file and archive manager](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l). For zip legacy charset detection by far2l to work properly, your system language setting should match the one set on the system where the archive was created (Windows' internal "zip folders" tool uses just the same logic). Also you can do

```
LANG=he_IL.UTF-8 far2l
```

Answer (score 0):

I have zip archive compressed in Linux (from command line) and filenames with diacritics characters are not correctly decompressed on Windows, but I succesfully unpacked it with [Bandizip](http://www.bandisoft.com/bandizip/) software which can set charset on toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem when extracting a file with Cyrillic symbols in the name using 'unzip'.

The problem was solved by using 'ark':

```
ark -ab archive.zip
```