# extracting filenames in ubuntu with non-latin encoding which were archived in windows

Tags: ubuntu, zip, character-encoding

This issue has been asked quite a lot (e.g [q1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/251969/how-can-i-correctly-decompress-a-zip-archive-of-files-with-hebrew-names), [q2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/362812/encoding-of-cyrillic-filenames-in-zip-files)), but is still far from solved , at least in Ubuntu 20.04 with the default zip tools (zip, file-roller).

The zip files are created in Windows, and in my case using Hebrew encoding for the filenames.

Following [this advice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613991/476798) I was able to correctly extract the correct filenames with the [far2l](https://github.com/elfmz/far2l) utility (built from source).

There has to be a better way for default filename handling of Windows based zip archives.

Any suggestions for a system oriented solution to this nagging issue

Comment: Try fixing Windows?

Comment: Can't say that Windows need "fixing". 
If you could'nt open a word or excel document in libreoffice you would'nt suggest to "fix" Microsoft office....